# pytest mock find, sort and limit functions from pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mocking, pytest

I have function, that I want test in pytest. In this function I make call to DB, nothing important. I want to mock this and after that mock count().

```
from app import mongo
img = mongo.db.images.find({"url": data, }).sort("date", -1).limit(1)
if img.count() > 0:
....
```

Is it possible? I tried with this code but not working.

```
@patch('app.main.mongo')
def test_images_(mock_requests):

    images_all_data = []
    mock_requests.db.images.find.return_value = images_all_data
```

Comment: Is the function to be tested defined in `app.main.py`? Also, I'm not sure if `sort` and `limit` are also a part of `mongo` and therefore patched - if that is the case, you will get back a mock instead of the list.

Comment: You probably have to mock the return value of `mongo.cursor.limit`, as this is what returns the final result (e.g. `img`).